# Electric surge on Magsafe connector

Tags: macbook, hardware-failure, macbook-pro

Noticed something very strange today while putting my MBP on charge. Attaching image.[image]

Bought the 13" retina MBP last month. I have no idea what it is but I suspect electric surge from incorrect grounded (earthed) electric socket. I'm not sure if they'll replace it or not, but going to take it to Apple service tomorrow. Has anyone faced such an issue?

Comment: I think maybe you mean "surge".  And it's hard to tell from the picture whether something's broken off of one side and gotten stuck to the other, or whether there's simply some glue or goo of some sort stuck there.

Comment: Yes I meant "surge". And it's kind of black glue deposited over. I tried scratching it but it's stuck in there. Nothing broken.

Comment: It could be some glue that oozed from the computer when it got hot.  (Or could be something that got stuck on there while the pieces were apart, then hardened with heat.)

Comment: (I don't see how an incorrect ground could have caused this -- many of the power cubes don't even have a ground connection, and everything is double-insulated.)